# Basic-Authentication in a Micronaut application

Tags: micronaut

I have a Micronaut application where the controllers are protected with JWT tokens. For this, I have enabled the bearer authentication method in the configuration.
I also generate Swagger documentation for the REST API, which is accessible via a static resource.
How can I now secure this static resource with Basic Authentication? It seems to me that only one authentication method can be defined, and in my case, that is already bearer.

This is my current application.yml (parts of it) with anonymous authentication for the swagger documentation:

```
micronaut:
  router:
    static-resources:
      default:
        paths: classpath:META-INF/static
        mapping: /static/**
      swagger:
        paths: classpath:META-INF/swagger
        mapping: /swagger/**
      redoc:
        paths: classpath:META-INF/swagger/views/redoc
        mapping: /redoc/**
      rapidoc:
        paths: classpath:META-INF/swagger/views/rapidoc
        mapping: /rapidoc/**
      swagger-ui:
        paths: classpath:META-INF/swagger/views/swagger-ui
        mapping: /swagger-ui/**

  security:
    authentication: bearer
    endpoints:
      login:
        enabled: true
      oauth:
        enabled: true
      keys:
        enabled: true
    token:
      jwt:
        enabled: true
        signatures:
          secret:
            generator:
              secret: 'itsmysecret'
        generator:
          access-token:
            expiration: 600 # 10min
          refresh-token:
            secret: 'itsmysecret'
            enabled: true
    intercept-url-map:
      - pattern: /static/*
        http-method: GET
        access:
          - isAnonymous()
      - pattern: /swagger-ui/*
        http-method: GET
        access:
          - isAnonymous()
      - pattern: /swagger/*
        http-method: GET
        access:
          - isAnonymous()
      - pattern: /redoc/*
        http-method: GET
        access:
          - isAnonymous()
      - pattern: /rapidoc/*
        http-method: GET
        access:
          - isAnonymous()
      - pattern: /health/*
        http-method: GET
        access:
          - isAnonymous()
```

Answer (score 0):

The authorization is basically driven by Authorization header of the http request. If you secure given path with access `isAuthenticated` then Micronaut will analyse if

1. An `Authorization` header is present
2. Will verify what Authorization Strategy should be use `Basic`, `Bearer`, …

According to the Micronaut Security documentation [Basic Authentication](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-security/latest/guide/#basicAuth) is supported out of the box.

Meaning the http request is requesting the Authorization strategy and that will be used, when your Micronaut application supports the Authorization strategy.

Furthermore `micronaut.security.authentication=bearer` should only be supplied if the service handles login and logout requests.